# Что такое SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Всем здравствуйте.
Только что задался таким вопросом: что такое SharedPreferences?
Это массив, состоящий из переменных, в который мы засовываем переменные?
Например:

```
sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();

Integer i = 0;
Integer value =  1;
while (i < 6) {
    editor.putInt("", value);
    editor.apply();
    value++;
    i++;
}
```

Что будет в SharedPreferences после этого кода?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это текстовый файл в формате XML с интерфейсом взаимодействия (класс и методы чтения-записи) по принципу организации: ключ-значение.

Первым аргументом метода чтения `getInt("key", def)`вы указываете ключ, это константа типа `String`, уникальное имя, по которому вы можете обратится к именно нужному значению, оно не должно быть "", а более осмысленным, как "MY_KEY"), второй аргумент - значение по умолчанию, оно будет использовано, если указанного первым аргументом ключа не окажется в файле настроек.

ps: "пустой" ключ (со значением "") компилятор вряд ли пропустит, но проверять мне лень.

При нормальном значении ключа, после выполнения вашего кода, там будет хранится только последнее значение `value` (число 6) все предыдущие значения будут затерты вновь добавляемым безвозвратно, то есть каждая новая запись по определенному ключу удаляет то, что было там ранее.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня есть ещё один вопрос. Чтобы получить переменную из SharedPreferenses, например Integer a = sPrefs.getInt("", 0); В скобках - это ключ к значению, а переменная в скобках - дефолтное значение?

Comment: добавил в ответ